# Complex JSON data for AngularJS nested ng-repeat

Tags: json, angularjs

I try to access to nested JSON data into nested JSON data. I use ng-repeat, it works for the nested JSON data but not for the nested nested.

The data I want to catch is the server URL and their name.

```
<tr ng-repeat="site in dT.data.sites">
  <td>{{ site.siteName }}</td>
  <td><span ng-repeat="country in site.countries">{{ country.country + ' '}}<br><br></span></td>
  <!-- Does not work -->
  <td><span ng-repeat="country in site.countries">{{ country.masters.name }}</span></td>
  <!-- Works, but displays only the first element of the array because of the [0] -->
  <td><span ng-repeat="country in site.countries">{{ country.masters[0].name }}</span></td>
  <!-- Does not work -->
  <td><span ng-repeat="master in site.countries.masters">{{ master.name }}</span></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

<kbd>[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/kwFhM5TqQLQm1aDOofD0?p=preview)</kbd>

Maybe I have to use a function with a if…else method.
Or use a service, but I would prefer to use ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do an `ng-repeat` inside another `ng-repeat`.  Something like this:

```
<td><span ng-repeat="country in site.countries"><span ng-repeat="master in country.masters">{{ master.name }}<br /></span></span></td>
```

I've made changes to your plunker to show this working:
http://plnkr.co/edit/PdHesQRAeEMq38AgjxTm?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<td><span ng-repeat="country in site.countries[0].masters">{{ country.server + ':' + country.name + ', ' }}</span></td>
```

see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ia3NuUTOu79LV3z0S2dj?p=preview)